# How to separating parts of a java string?

Tags: java, string, double

I've got this string:

```
"type":"image","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":135,"top":259,"width":270,"height":519,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"src":"file:///C:/Users/Alvin%20Combrink/Dropbox/Entrepren%C3%B6rskap/Design/Hemsidan/Backgrunder/Labyrint.jpg","filters":[]},
```

each part is seperated by a comma, i want to be able to extract a few of the numbers into doubles. The ones i want are `left`, `top`, `scaleX`, `scaleY` and `angle`. How shall i approch this?

thanks

Comment: Are you by any chance dealing with JSON?

Comment: haha how did you know?

Comment: By the pairs, it must be JSON

Comment: Ok, any clue on how to do this?

Comment: Use an actual JSON parser. There are many frameworks out there, starting with `org.json` or [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: This is for school so i thought i'd try to do code everything... Isn't there a way to make a string-array and set each on to be after a comma?

Comment: @user2961869 B'coz, that's the syntax for JSON. And ideally you should be using a JSON parser for this task, which will really simplify it. You can go through this tutorial - http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-json-tutorials/ for some usage.

Comment: Don't i have to use other code than my own? I think ill go with a 'split' method... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that someone already replied, but I've been doing this, hope that help too:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String text ="\"type\":\"image\",\"originX\":\"center\",\"originY\":\"center\",\"left\":135,\"top\":259,\"width\":270,\"height\":519,\"fill\":\"rgb(0,0,0)\",\"overlayFill\":null,\"stroke\":null,\"strokeWidth\":1,\"strokeDashArray\":null,\"strokeLineCap\":\"butt\",\"strokeLineJoin\":\"miter\",\"strokeMiterLimit\":10,\"scaleX\":1,\"scaleY\":1,\"angle\":0,\"flipX\":false,\"flipY\":false,\"opacity\":1,\"shadow\":null,\"visible\":true,\"clipTo\":null,\"src\":\"file:///C:/Users/Alvin%20Combrink/Dropbox/Entrepren%C3%B6rskap/Design/Hemsidan/Backgrunder/Labyrint.jpg\"";
            //Just left and scaleX for example
        String left = readValue(text, "left");
        String scaleX = readValue(text, "scaleX");

        System.out.println("left:" + left);
        System.out.println("scaleX:" + scaleX);
     }

    public static String readValue(String text, String key)
    {
        //search for the init of the value
        int start = text.indexOf("\"" + key + "\"");
        //search for the end of the value
        int end = text.indexOf(",", start + key.length() + 3);

        //return the value. these + 3 , is for quotes and ":"
        return text.substring(start + key.length() + 3,end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was even better! :D

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to rely on using JSON parsers (you should, though, if you are using JSON a lot), you could use the `split`-method on the entire string and split according to `,` (comma), find the chunks of data that you want, split those according to `:` and read the data directly from the 2nd slot in the resulting array.

You may need to substring the last `"` to be able to parse the numbers directly, though.

But like I said, you really do want to use a JSON parser of some kind if you are using JSON more than a few times in your program.

Code example:

```
String abc = "ABC:123,DEF:456,GHI:789";
String[] chucks = abc.split(",");
String[] oneToThree = chunks[0].split(":");
String nums = oneToThree[1];
System.out.println(nums);
//This will print 123
```